# Javascript closure confusing

Tags: javascript, closures

I was experimenting with Javascript closure and the below code keeps printing 9 always. But as i am creating 10 closures shouldn't previous values persist?

```
var arr = [];
function getModule(value){
        return (function (_value) {
              var m_val = _value;

              this.getValue = function () {
                  return m_val;
              };

              return {
                ShowValue: function () {
                    console.log(getValue.call(this));
                }
              };
        })(value);
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    arr.push(getModule(i))
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    arr[i].ShowValue();
}
```

Please help understand this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But as i am creating 10 closures shouldn't previous persist?

You're creating them, but then immediately overwriting them with the next one. `this` in your anonymous function is a reference to the global object (also available as `window` on browsers), so each `this.getValue = ...` *overwrites* the one before. The reason it's a reference to the global object is that the way you're calling that function doesn't set any specific `this`, so it defaults to the global object (this is something "strict" mode changes; see more below). More about how `this` works in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Just use a function declaration, rather than assigning to a property of `this`:

```
function getValue() {
    return m_val;
}
```

Also note that there's no reason to set `this` when calling it, so:

```
console.log(getValue.call(this));
```

becomes

```
console.log(getValue());
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr = [];
function getModule(value){
        return (function (_value) {
              var m_val = _value;
              
              function getValue() {
                  return m_val;
              }

              return {
                ShowValue: function () {
                    console.log(getValue());
                }
              };
        })(value);
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    arr.push(getModule(i))
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    arr[i].ShowValue();
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Some other notes:

- There's no need for that inner anonymous function at all, and no need for `getValue`; just use `value` directly:

  ```
  function getModule(value){
      return {
        ShowValue: function () {
            console.log(value);
        }
      };
  }
  ```

  There's nothing the code calling `getModule` can do that will change the value in `value`; `value` is entirely private to `getModule` and its contents. It has a *copy* of the value passed into it (indirectly) from `i`, it's not a reference to or alias for `i`.
- The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that non-constructor functions start with a lower-case letter, so `showValue` rather than `ShowValue` (even when they're methods; think `console.log` or `Math.max`).
- `var` applies throughout the scope (global scope or a specific function's scope) in which it appears. The two `var i` declarations in your code are not scoped to the loop, so the second one is unnecessary (but permitted by the language). (ES2015+ have `let` and `const` which *would* be scoped to the loop, but `var` isn't.)
- As of ECMAScript fifth edition (2009), JavaScript has a "strict" mode which changes some of the behavior of the language, including what `this` is in a function that is called without doing anything that would set `this`. (`this` is `undefined` in that situation instead of referring to the global object.) Strict mode also has other benefits, like flagging it up if you accidentally use a variable you haven't declared. To enable it, put `"use strict";` at the top of the code. More about strict mode [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

So:

```js
"use strict";
var i;
var arr = [];
function getModule(value){
    return {
      showValue: function () {
          console.log(value);
      }
    };
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr.push(getModule(i))
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr[i].showValue();
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend OP to putt `'use strict'` at the top of the code. This would've made the issue with the code more apparent.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm: ...and it's just good advice 99.9999% of the time anyway. :-) Done.